# Protractor & Angular 8: Set localStorage before Angular app runs?

Tags: protractor, angular8

I have some E2E testing requirements where I need to mock some data through localStorage, but I'm having a hard time getting localStorage set before Angular runs. The app eventually does see the localStorage item I set, but only after Angular is well into running component code and making HTTP requests. Here is what I have tried:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  // Attempt #1
  browser.get('/');
  browser.executeScript(`window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');`);

  // Attempt #2
  browser.get('/').then(() => {
    return browser.executeScript(`window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');`);
  });
});
```

Does Protractor have some other mechanism to accomplish this? Or maybe some other creative way of injecting data into an Angular app before it loads on a per-spec (or browser.get) basis? Thanks!

Comment: localStorage of your app doesn't exist until you load the page. So how can you set it before? Or I didn't understand the question

Comment: I'm mainly looking for a way to perform an action to the browser instance after the browser opens, but before Angular loads/runs. I have already moved on and I am now just passing some data through the URL in `browser.get()`, but I'd still be interested to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you set up this in the `onPrepare` hook in the [protractor config file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L497).

This can be used if the preparation involves any asynchronous calls, e.g. interacting with the browser.

in config:

```
onPrepare() {
  return browser.get('/').then(() => {
    return browser.executeScript(`window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');`);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I might have a use for this for something else, but I'll still need a way to set local storage in a beforeEach or beforeAll, for example. Is there a spec-level equivalent of onPrepare?

Comment: Why you don't want to put it in the `onPrepare` besides you can use the `beforeEach` and `beforeAll` functions inside the `onPrepare` function.